# VBA write note "system" - Look if cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I'am trying go make a small note system, and i have tried to write a code and iam stuck in the last part.

Basically I'am making a project which is retreiveing data from a database. I want to make function where a employee are able to write a note and should save them in colum L, M, N.

The requirements are

When i write in colum E (write note) and clik "save notes"  it should;

1. it should take the data from the cell and insert it in A together with the date from colum D.
2. It should copy the note and place it in colum L (E-note 1) if that is not empty then go colum M               (E-note 2). It should also copy the date from colum D.
3. it should delete the note from colum E.
4. When i write a new note in the same row it should do step 1, 2 and 3.

There is a link to the picture [image]

```
Sub Test()
'Saves note
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
If [E9999].End(xlUp).Row <= 3 Then Exit Sub 'Will exit sub if column E is empty
    Set Rng = Range("E4:E" & [E9999].End(xlUp).Row) 'Defines column E's range to be used
            
        For Each c In Rng
        Let i = c.Row
            If Not IsEmpty(c) And IsEmpty(c.Offset(, -1)) And IsEmpty(c.Offset(, -3)) Then
                Range("A" & i) = Range("E" & i).Value
                Range("B" & i) = Application.UserName 'Retreives value from Computer's Username
                Range("D" & i) = Format(Now())   'Datestamp
                
                'Input value in first non empty L, M, or N column
                If Range("L" & i) = "" Then
                        Range("L" & i) = c.Value
                    ElseIf Range("L" & i) <> "" And Range("M" & i) = "" Then
                        Range("M" & i) = c.Value
                    ElseIf Range("L" & i) <> "" And Range("M" & i) <> "" And Range("N" & i) = "" Then
                        Range("N" & i) = c.Value
                    Else
                End If
            End If
        Next
Rng.ClearContents 'Deletes values in column E
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Hey @SRJ - I need help with step 1, 2, 3

Comment: That's not really how this place works. You get stuck on a particular thing and ask for help on that, not just present a list of requirements. What does your code currently do?

Comment: Sorry about that. Currently if i write a note in colum E and click on "save notes" it saves the note in colum A "latest note" and generate a username and the time stamp, and lastly it puts the note into colum L. Where i'm stuck is putting the date into colum A and column L, and i cannot make the function where checks if something is is colum L, then it should write the note in colum M instead.

Comment: This line `If Not IsEmpty(cel) And IsEmpty(cel.Offset(, -1)) And IsEmpty(cel.Offset(, -3)) Then` ensures that there will never ever be a value written to column `M`, because on your first entry the values in columns `B` and `D` (and column `L`) will be written. You will have to explain the conditions under which this should happen anyway: e.g.  if the current user's name is in column `B` of the same row where the note was written, or... Do elaborate on the note with date e.g. Test1 30/11/2020 which is supposed to be written to columns A and L,M,N...are there more; what if N is already full?